# Set Custom Component Height/Width Programatically

Tags: android, view, custom-controls, android-layout, tablelayout

I have a custom component where I know the width and height is always as follows:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I would like to avoid having to specify the width and height in XML since any other settings are wrong.

I've tried a lot of things, but nothing works.  For example, this code doesn't work:

```
public class MyLayout extends ViewGroup {...

LayoutParams layoutParams = 
new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

but no matter what I do, I get the exception message "You must supply a layout_width attribute." which goes away if I put back the XML `layout_width`, `layout_height`.

I've also tried to Override `onFinishInflate()`, but that never gets called.  I tried inheriting from `View`, `ViewGroup` and `TableLayout`.  I've tried calling `getLayoutParams()`, but it returns null.

How do I get my custom component to not need these specified in XML?

Please no snark.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/use-dip-sp-metrics-programmatically/ and instead of setWidth try setMinWidth Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You have the answer,

LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(width, height); 
setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

height and width are specified in px, dip, sp

Alternatively, some of them provide with setHeight and setWidth methods, you can use them.

Comment: As I mentioned, that does not work.  It executes, but still throws the same exception sometime after construction.  Thanks though.

Comment: height and width is provided in which one? px, dip or sp? it can't be all of them at once, right? Suppose I do new LayoutParams(10, 10), is it 10 dip? 10 px? 10 sp?